# XMLHttpRequest cannot load spservices

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, spservices

I use SpServices to do CRUD operations, When I execute this code:

```
$().SPServices({
    operation: "UpdateListItems",
    async: false,
    batchCmd: "Update",
    listName: "Event",
    ID: idevent,
    valuepairs: [["ows_Nbr_Billet_Disponible", nouveauNombrebillet]],
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
        alert(nouveauNombrebillet);
    }
});
```

I get this error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://sharepointrecette:43434343/sites/A/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx. Cross
>   origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data,
>   chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.send @
>   jquery-1.11.1.min.js:4m.extend.ajax @
>   jquery-1.11.1.min.js:4ao.fn.SPServices @
>   jquery.SPServices-2014.02.min.js:19updateListEvent @
>   SessionEvent.js:119inscriptionEvent @ SessionEvent.js:110onclick @
>   inscriptionevent:677

The fact is my port is not http://sharepointrecette:43434343 but http://sharepointrecette:4343, How it could be changed or doubled

Any idea ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only web application in your farm with the server name and a port number visible in the URL should be Central Administration. Any other web application should have a host header entry and work on port 80 (or 443 for https). Once that is configured correctly, your error will go away.

There are lots of resources on the web that explain how to configure a web application with its own host header on port 80. [Here](http://thuansoldier.net/?p=1323), for example.

Answer (score 0):

If you are accessing web application other then at port 80 (or 443 in case of https) you need to use host header web application or AAM. just create AAM or Host header web application for that particular web application issue would be resolved.